# Why we need RIA?

Tags: html, rich-internet-application

Why we need RIA ? I didn't see any benefits from RIA？　it need a plugin to run it, this will bring headache to its user, compared to the regular html page.

Thanks.

Comment: If you need a plugin for it then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Retagging assuming that by RIA you meant "Rich Internet Application"

Comment: Adobe Air RIA needs the flash plugin, JavaFX needs JRE plugin. is it correct ?

Comment: HTML and JavaScript are native to most browsers.

Comment: I'd start by defining what "RIA" is actually supposed to mean. Since the advent of AJAX and especially HTML5, *internet applications* can be very *rich* without any sort of plugin.

Answer (score 3):

1. RIA, or Rich Internet Applications, came as a ready solution to the problem of slackened Web browsing and low customer conversion rate.
2. RIA offers richer functionality by making use of HTML widgets available on standard browser-based Web applications.
3. Rich Internet Applications are providing users a multi-dimensional experience.

With the use of RIA, a part of the application runs directly within the users’ Web browser, allowing automatic navigation. It is a major improvement on traditional HTML and has transformed the static database of a website to a multi-functional online experience. Now, shoppers can see, “feel” and even try products online. RIA ensures large scale business returns and repeat visits, giving a boost to online business.

Comment: Do you have an example ?

Comment: Sorry, but… does that actually mean anything? This is such a high-level marketing description that I can derive no actual information from it.